# Asp.net Core Angular Template Router-outlet not clearing correctly

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, single-page-application

I have started with the angular spa template from the asp.net core 2 release.  I first noticed after making changes in VS and saving, the browser would refresh but the content was duplicate, triplicated....etc.

I am now doing some basic component routing with one router-outlet area.  I have attempted to use routerlink in the html and router navigate and navigatebyurl in code with same results.  On the first navigate, the new content is loaded but the original content is not cleared.  If I hit the navigate button again, it reloads correctly.   I also tested the paths by directly entering into the browser and everything works as normal.  Since I am running in dev mode, don't know if it has something to do with the live refresh or what or if it has the .net template has implemented angular spa.

Nothing fancy at all , no routeguards or anything else

Love the ability to have mvc webapi controllers in same project as angular , but really has been a pain so far.

```
*****************
Routing Module
    @NgModule({
        imports: [
                RouterModule.forRoot([
                    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
                    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
                    { path: 'maint/uom/:id', component: UomDetailComponent },
                    { path: 'maint/uom', component: UomMaintenanceComponent },
                    { path: 'httptest', component: HttpTestComponent},
                    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
                ]),
            ],
            exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }

*******************************************

//navigate in ts file
     showUomDetail(uom: IUom) {
            console.log(uom);
            this._router.navigate(['/maint/uom', uom.id]);

           // this._router.navigateByUrl('/maint/uom/5');
            //route to detail page
        }


*****
HTML snippet
     <a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/httptest']">View</a>

*****
app.component.html
<div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class="row">
        <nav-menu></nav-menu>
    </div>
     <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-sm-9 body-content'>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the best way to show, but here is a link to google drive for a video.   https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwI9FAmKVvK_NHRTWG5feGx4SDg.  The product detail is a new component and not hidden content on the page with the grid which is why direct access via the url or via the A tags at the bottom works.  Thanks

Comment: What do your router-outlet(s) look like? Are you using any of the components as directives? (ie using the components selector property inside other html)?

Comment: At this point very simple.  One router outlet using a bootstrap menu...added snippet to the code above.  Similar things happens if I make a change while server is running, when the page auto refreshes, it can be duplicated as well until I force a refresh.

Comment: your `index.html` ?

Comment: I figured it out.  It was the browserAnimationModule.  Don't remember what had me add it , but when I removed it, everything started working well again.

Answer (score 5):

I finally started pulling components back out of the app until I found it.  It was the BrowserAnimationModule.  Once I pulled it out, everything worked as expected.

Comment: You save my day.